# How do I exclude some names from my top list

Tags: php, mysql

This code displays a list of all the names that are stored in the database in the table "entries".

I have a list of 200 names. The top 20 is marked in green. Last 20 red. Others are blue.

```
$position=0;

$upit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY votes DESC");
  //This is now an array of the data

while ($model = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) {
$position++;
$data = unserialize($model['data']);
$max = mysql_num_rows($upit);
$max = $max - 20;

if ($position < 21){
echo "  <font color=#008000> ".$position." )  ".$data[6]['value']."  ( ".$model[votes]." ) </font>";

} elseif ($position <= $max) {
echo "  <font color=#000080> ".$position." )  ".$data[6]['value']."  ( ".$model[votes]." ) </font>";

} else {
echo "  <font color=#FF0000> ".$position." )  ".$data[6]['value']."  ( ".$model[votes]." ) </font>";
}
}
```

This CODE displays a list in the following way

```
 1. Novak Djokovic (1342) 
 2. Rafael Nadal (1234) 
 3. Roger Federer (1002)
 4. Name 4 (990) 
 5. Name 5 (899) 
 6. ...
```

Now I want to out of list two names from the list but they are not deleted from the database.
Each name has its own unique ID in the table "entries" a field called "entries_id".

For example, I want to Out of list 
Novak Djokovic whose "entries_id" is "150" 
and Roger Federes hose "entries_id" is "92"

Comment: Throw OUT!!!!
What does that mean?

Comment: Do you want that to be deleted from the database, or the list which you are having in the front end?

Comment: I want to remain on the list. Just so it does not show.

Comment: Just do it in PHP itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply update your query accordingly

```
SELECT * FROM entries WHERE entries_id<>150 AND entries_id<>92 ORDER BY votes DESC
```

And you won't get those two records in your result even when they exist in database like you want.

Comment: Or use `NOT IN (150, 92)`, so you don't need to retype `entries_id<>?` every single time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
$count = 0;
while ($model = mysql_fetch_array($upit)) {
    $position++;
    $data = unserialize($model['data']);
    $max = mysql_num_rows($upit);
    $max = $max - 20;

    if (!($data[6]['value'] == 150 || $data[6]['value'] == 92)){
        $count++;
        if ($count< 21){
            echo "  <font color=#008000> ".$position." )  ".$data[6]['value']."  (".$model[votes]." ) </font>";
        } elseif ($count<= $max) {
            echo "  <font color=#000080> ".$position." )  ".$data[6]['value']."  ( ".$model[votes]." ) </font>";
        } else {
            echo "  <font color=#FF0000> ".$position." )  ".$data[6]['value']."  ( ".$model[votes]." ) </font>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just like going to market, buying all the chocolates available and after getting home saying oh no I don't need Dairy Milk. Why get all those in the first place? If some records are not needed they shouldn't be fetched from the db to start with.

Comment: I agree with you, but this is what he asked for. He asked for a piece of code that threated the resultset in the front-end.